# How to generate row numbers (1, 2, 3, ...) when bind the custom table to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

We have Vue.js project with custom table bound to array. It looks as following:

[image]

The key part of HTML code looks as following:

```
<InfiniteScroll ref="scroller" :disable="finished" @load="onLoad">
  <swipeable-table
    v-if="waitingList.length"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="waitingList"
    :loading="loading"
    custom-width
    outerBorder
  >
    <template slot="rows" slot-scope="{ item: booking }">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ 0 }}</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ fullName(booking.user) }}</td>
        <td>{{ unitName(booking.search_by) }}</td>
        ...
      </tr>
    </template>
  </swipeable-table>
  ...
</InfiniteScroll>
```

The `waitingList` is an array of objects.

The part of JavaScript code looks as following:

```
methods: {
  fullName(user) {
    return fullName.by(user, null, true)
  },
  unitName(unit) {
    return unit?.name ?? ''
  },
  ...
```

The table is scrollable that is it shows 30 items at the beginning and after you scroll next 30 items (30+30=60) and so on.

The array of objects looks as following:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to use some JavaScript method to achieve it? If not how can I do it?

Comment: I see that slot-scope="{ item: booking }" may have other data in it. Usually it has something like index (vuetify data-table has it) . Try to check the data the slot-scope provide, maybe there is index data that you could use

Comment: I've just updated my post. Please, take a look at it.

Comment: you can use `booking.id`

Comment: I'm no Vue, expert, so I'm not going to touch this, instead maybe you should map the waitingList array so that it has a property that has index.... waitingList.map((value,index)=>{...value, index: index}); something like this.

Comment: @Laxmikant Dange The row numbers should be 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: I really want to know what the slot-scope provide, can you do something like this  ' slot-scope="{ item: booking, ...rest } ' and in the first td , to check what it contain other than item, '<td>{{JSON.stringify(rest)}}</td>' , maybe it contain something you could use, CMIIW

Comment: try `slot-scope="{ item: booking, index:index  }"`

Comment: @Laxmikant Dange Yes! Please, answer my question in regular way and I'll mark it as the correct one. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add index in the same way as item in template.

```
<template slot="rows" slot-scope="{ item: booking,index:index }">
  <tr>
    <td>{{ index }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{ fullName(booking.user) }}</td>
    <td>{{ unitName(booking.search_by) }}</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</template>
```